# can you write scripts to modify flow tables for the SDN controller?

Tags: opendaylight

Im new to SDN and OPenDayLight. I was wondering if you could write custom scripts to modify flow tables for the SDN controller?

Answer (score 0):

absolutely. you can interact with ODL via REST interface and write your scripts
to CRUD (create, read, update, delete) flows. There would be many ways to go
about this, python scripts, bash scripts, etc.